# Gamma exposure assumption

Tags: gamma

When coming to calculate Gamma exposure (or Greek exposure), it's common to assume that traders are buying puts and selling calls to hedge underlining positions. Brokers are doing the opposite: selling puts and buying calls. However, by looking at volume and open interests, this assumption may not be always true because some traders may sell puts and buy calls too. How to estimate the order flow is on buy or sell side? It seems the VIX is one of such evidence: when VIX is rising, traders will buy puts.